# Layout manager in java for a custom file explorer

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I am creating my own file explorer in Java and am looking for a layout that helps me place the components (files) inside a panel in rows and columns (like a file manager in windows). The panel dynamically changes based on the folder's content. So I have to make sure that the files I place in change row every time they reach the horizontal "border" of the panel . Also, the icons I use for every file type has the same size and when i resize the window they have to "fill in" each row.Any other idea about how i can create this would be helpful.

Example of what I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: Weak title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `JList`.

The default is to just display a horizontal list but you can change that to display the data in rows and columns.

You can also set a renderer to display an `Icon` instead of text.

If you want both an `Icon` and text you will need to create a custom renderer.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information and working examples.